# How to shutdown/reboot a Ubuntu system using Ruby

Tags: ruby, docker

I have a problem using `system 'reboot'` on my Sinatra application.

I got a success response, but the reboot action doesn't happen.

I also tried `exec 'reboot'`, but got the same response.

If I run this without the Docker container it works.

Comment: Are you sure your user has permissions to perform this operation?

Comment: I executed the command on irb, it works. But inside the application it is not working.

Comment: @StephenM : What do you want to achieve? Restarting the docker? I don't think you can reboot your host from within a docker application.

Comment: @user1934428 I want to reboot the host machine.

Comment: I'm not very knowledgeable about docker, but from [this](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/6401) already pretty old discussion, I would expect that this security hole has been fixed already.

Comment: I'n not sure why *any* command would behave differently in irb vs within an application. Maybe it's running as a different user? Maybe your irb session wasn't actually within the docker container? I'm also not sure why you'd want to reboot a host machine via a sinatra application!

Comment: A `docker` container is a virtual environment. The `reboot` command executed within docker pertains to the virtual system that `docker` is creating, not the host system. You can run your docker image in such a way as to give you a shell prompt from docker and try it there as a test, but it should not reboot your host system.

Comment: This is not a Sinatra problem, it's an innocent bystander.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Use Semaphore Flags to Signal the Host

You can't directly reboot a host from within a Docker container. That would violate basic security principles. Pragmatically, though, you can mount host directories inside your Docker container. That opens up a number of possibilities.

In your case, if you're sure you want to do this and that it won't create disruption for other containers, services, or users, then one approach would be to:

1. Mount a subdirectory from the host’s */tmp* or */var/tmp* inside your Docker container.
2. Have your Sintra application write an empty semaphore file like `trigger_reboot` into the mounted subdirectory when the route is triggered.
3. Have a cron job on the host that looks for the semaphore file each minute, and then executes a privileged shutdown script when it's present.

### Caveats and Considerations

This will work, but be aware of a few simple caveats:

- Your privileged script should be separate from the semaphore file to avoid executing arbitrary commands on the host from within a container.
- Your priviliged script should remove the semaphore file *before* triggering the shutdown or reboot.
- You should have an init script, @reboot cron job, or initialization routine in your web application to ensure that:

  - The necessary directory structures in your temporary directory are recreated when the computer or web application restarts.
  - The semaphore flag was really removed after a restart, so you don't get stuck in a reboot loop.
- Your privileged reboot script will need to run SUID root, or at least as a pre-authorized command defined in your *sudoers* file.

It's possible to do what you want with semaphores and a related set of processes on the host system, but you definitely need to take security and robustness into consideration to do this safely and reliably.